# Image parsing in rss in android

Tags: android, rss

I am trying to parse RSS feeds from a news website but I am unable to fetch the images from the rss feeds. Can someone suggest me some easy implementation for parsing RSS feeds with images in Android.

Comment: it depends how the images are referenced in the feed. Look at the source code of the feed, and tell us how the image is displayed. It might be an url

Comment: The images are referenced inside the feeds in the <media:content> tag of the <item> tag as an url.

Comment: Hey! Same problem here. Is there a general way for solving this?

Answer (score 0):

For XML Parsing in Android there is three ways to achieve it.

That are,

1. Using DOM Parser
2. Using SAX Parser
3. XML Pull Parser

check this [Article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html): it tells every thing about it.